# script to cat every other (even) line in a set of files together while leaving the odd lines unchanged

Tags: python, command-line, line, cat, fasta

I have a set of three .fasta files of standardized format. Each one begins with a string that acts as a header on line 1, followed by a long string of nucleotides on line 2, where the header string denotes the animal that the nucleotide sequence came from. There are 14 of them altogether, for a total of 28 lines, and each of the three files has the headers in the same order. A snippet of one of the files is included below as an example, with the sequences shortened for clarity.

> anas-crecca-crecca_KSW4951-mtDNA
> ATGCAACCCCAGTCCTAGTCCTCAGTCTCGCATTAG...CATTAG
> anas-crecca-crecca_KGM021-mtDNA
> ATGCAACCCCAGTCCTAGTCCTCAGTCTCGCATTAG...CATTAG
> anas-crecca-crecca_KGM020-mtDNA
> ATGCAACCCCAGTCCTAGTCCTCAGTCTCGCATTAG...CATTAG

What I would like to do is write a script or program that *cat*s each of the strings of nucleotides together, but keeps them in the same position. My knowledge, however, is limited to rudimentary python, and I'd appreciate any help or tips someone could give me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = ""

with open('filename.fasta') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        i=i+1
        if (i%2 == 0):
            data = data + line[:-1]

# Copy and paste above block for each file, 
# replacing filename with the actual name.

print(data)
```

Remember to replace "filename.fasta" with your actual file name!

**How it works**

- Variable i acts as a line counter, when it is even, i%2 will be zero and the new line is concatenated to the "data" string. This way, the odd lines are ignored.
- The [:-1] at the end of the data line removes the line break, allowing you to add all sequences to the same line.

Comment: That worked. Thank you, I wasn't sure on how to implement a line counter.